# Uploading Large Content Version via REST API

Tags: files

We are working for one of our client to access the Salesforce REST API for uploading Files/Content in Salesforce Libraries.

Each File Size is nearly equal to 1.5 GB. I see the Limits of Content Files as 2 GB BUT uploading these files via Visualforce / Ajax ends us at the "Max String Exceeded" or Heap Size Limit Errors.

Does anyone have tried uploading Large Files to Salesforce via REST API. I am calling the standard REST API available for Conten.

-Thanks

Comment: What code have you been working with ?I had success in past using forceTK library    https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/01/spring-15-preview-cors-force-com-rest-api.html

Comment: I had tried using ForceTK Library but it seems to be failing at 150 MB itself with Bad Request Error. So - tried using Ajax Requests & after that using Normal Visualforce Page.

The Big Problem which I see is - They are looking for MASS UPLOADING of Files which I am not sure upto What Size Salesforce will allow.

Comment: Could you post the code you used?  I'm confused as to how you're implementing the REST API with VF.  In addition, do you have any triggers enabled on the ContentVersion/ContentDocument/FeedItem objects?